# Read csv and check for term in file

Tags: python, file-io

```
import csv

word = input("please enter a word: ")
file = open('TEST.csv', 'r')

if column[0] in word or column[1] in word or column[2] in word or column[3] in word or column[4] in word:
    print("The word you entered if in row " +str(count))
else:
    print("The word you entered is NOT in row " +str(count))
```

My code is not working, I want the code to allow me to enter a word and find if it is in a csv file, then it should tell me if it is or if it isn't.

Comment: You never define the column variable or close the file, or read data from the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

word = input("please enter a word: ")
file = open('TEST.csv', 'r')
read = csv.reader(file)
count = 0

for column in read:
    count = count + 1

if column[0] in word or column[1] in word or column[2] in word or column[3] in word or column[4] in word:
    print("The word you entered if in row " +str(count))
else:
    print("The word you entered is NOT in row " +str(count))
```

This code won't work because you have an undefined 'count'. Also you need the program to be able to read the file and you missed that little bit of code. Also because you have columns that you are reading from you should have a

```
for column in read:
count = count + 1
```

Don't forget to set 'count' as a variable in itself.
Good luck

Comment: Damn, I was ninja'd

Answer (score 1):

There are a few fundamental problems in your code.

1. You never use your import csv
2. You never define the `count` variable
3. You never define the `column` list
4. You never read any data from the file
5. You never close the file

I hate to completely rewrite someone's code, but your code needs a bit of help. This code will accomplish what you want it to:

```
word = input("Please enter a word: ")
delimiter = ","

with open("TEST.csv", 'r') as file:
    content = file.read().replace('\n', '').split(delimiter)

if word in content:
    print("The word you entered is in row {}".format(content.index(word)))
else:
    print("The word you enterd is NOT in the file")
```

Let me walk you through what this code does and how.

1. We get our input like you were, with [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)
2. We use [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) to open our file and automatically close it when we are done
3. We [read](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) the file as one big string, [replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) all the line breaks ("\n") with empty strings and [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the string on commas. We split the string into a list on commas because this is a csv file, meaning everything is separated by commas. If you use a different delimiter, just change the delimiter variable.
4. Test if the word appears anywhere in the list.
5. (a) If it does appear, print that it does, along with it's index (it's row)

   (b) If it does not appear, print that it does not